# How call a function from addEventListener in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm doing an infinite scroll in ReactJS but I'm in trouble!

After my component loads, I do this:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        var h = this.innerHeight;
        var j = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        var k = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if ((h + k) >= j - 150) {
            loadPhotos();
        }
    });
}
```

and, as a magic, I've "loadPhotos() is not defined". I can't use this.loadPhotos() because it refers to window (that hasn't loadPhotos()).

I initialize my loadPhotos() in the constructor() method:

```
this.loadPhotos = this.loadPhotos.bind(this);
```

My loadPhotos() is defined outside the constructor() method, I mean that is defined in the class body.

Someone can help me? Thank you guys!

## SOLUTION

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => { // arrow boys
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var j = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        var k = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if ((h + k) >= j - 150) {
            this.loadPhotos();
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an arrow function as the callback, and this will refer to the component's instance.

Because the original `this` inside the callback referred to `window`, you also need to change `this.innerHeight` to `window.innerHeight`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('scroll', () => { // arrow function
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var j = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        var k = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if ((h + k) >= j - 150) {
            this.loadPhotos(); // now you can use this
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Man, thank you for your reply!
It solves but not at all. The `var h` goes to "undefined" and so my if doesn't work :S

So stupid, I update my question with the solution, love you man!

Comment: @Stackedo - You're welcome :) No need to update the answer with the solution, just [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use your way,
You would fix issue by using `let _self = this`.

Like this

```
componentDidMount() {
    let _self = this;
    window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
        var h = window.innerHeight;
        var j = document.documentElement.scrollHeight;
        var k = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        if ((h + k) >= j - 150) {
            _self.loadPhotos();
        }
    });
}
```